# How do I lock a window to part of the screen without it disappearing when I click on the window underneath?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to lock a window to part of the screen in Windows 10 without it disappearing when I click on the window underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few methods to do this.  There are several programs that will force a window to be always on top.  You can also use an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script (found in the link below).  While you can easily google for these, here is the first result I found:

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/windows-programs-always-on-top/

Comment: You provide useful references, but they may not always be available, so it's best to make at least part of your answer self-contained, e.g.., include the AutoKey script in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the inbuilt compilers in Windows 10 - there are three VB.NET compilers and three C# compilers - just copy each text file into the same folder and double click the batch file to make the program. The name is the first line in each of the two files.

---

```
@Echo Off
Echo TopMost.bat
Echo This file compiles TopMost.vb to TopMost.exe
Echo TopMost.exe set a window on top or not
Echo To use 
Echo     TopMost Top ^
Echo     TopMost Not ^
Echo E.G.
Echo     TopMost Top Untitled - Notepad
Echo -----------------------------------------------------
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%~dp0\TopMost.exe" "%~dp0\TopMost.vb" 
pause
```

---

```
'TopMost.vb
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module TopMost
 Public Declare UNICODE Function FindWindowW Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
 Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
 Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
 Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
 Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
 Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2


 Sub Main()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim hWindows as IntPtr
  Dim CmdLine as String
  Dim Ret as Integer
  CmdLine = Mid(Command(),5)
  hwindows = FindWindowW(vbNullString, CmdLine)
  If hwindows = 0 then
   Msgbox(Cmdline & " cannot be found.")
  Else
   If LCase(Left(Command(), 3)) = LCase("Top") then
    Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)
    If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox("Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError)
   ElseIf LCase(Left(Command(), 3)) = LCase("Not") then
    Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)
    If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox("Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError)
   Else
    Msgbox("Command line not recognised")
   End If
  End If
 End Sub
End Module
```

---

To use with notepad

```
"c:\folder with file\topmost.exe" top Untitled - Notepad
```

From https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/topmostexe-set-window-on-top-or-not.html